# AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to take screenshot of a webpage using Selenium webdriver, but cannot get it to work. I've added firefox as a Path environment variable and rebooted my system, added specified the path of the Geckodriver, even tried doing the same with Chromedriver, but nothing seems to work. The code I've used is added below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\ris09\Desktop\ChessReader\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win32', firefox_binary=binary)
```

Here's the error message that I'm getting:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15324\3615299261.py in 
2
3 binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox')
----> 4 browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\ris09\Desktop\ChessReader\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win32', firefox_binary=binary)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py in **init**(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, service_args, service, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
190         if not self.service:
191             self.service = Service(executable_path, service_args=service_args, log_path=service_log_path)
--> 192         self.service.start()
193
194         executor = FirefoxRemoteConnection(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
102         count = 0
103         while True:
--> 104             self.assert_process_still_running()
105             if self.is_connectable():
106                 break

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
113     def assert_process_still_running(self) -> None:
114         """Check if the underlying process is still running."""
--> 115         return_code = self.process.poll()
116         if return_code:
117             raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")

AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Comment: your path to FirefoxBinary is not a raw string (misses a `r` before the quotes) and you are using single backslashes. That means it will try to interpret `\P` and `\M`. Use raw strings, double backslashes or forward slashes but don't use single backslashes for paths

Comment: I tried doing that too but it didn't help either

Comment: From what I know the `executable_path` must be passed via `Service` (`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`) in the following way `webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path))`

Comment: However, you should be able to use the Firefox driver without a path environment variable, simply put `geckodriver.exe` in your python folder and then run `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` (it works for me). In my case the python folder is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`